# How to provide custom nginx error_pages

Tags: nginx, proxy, custom-error-pages

Need to provide custom error pages on nginx. Currently config looks like below:

```html
error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 /500.html;
        error_page 502 /502.html;
        location ~ ^/(404.html|500.html|502.html){
           root /etc/nginx/error-pages;
        }
```

It works for urls like https://example.com/404, but it doesn't for https://example.com/404/404
How to make it work ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We will create a location block for the file, where we are able to ensure that the root matches our file system location and that the file is only accessible through internal Nginx redirects:

```
error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error-pages;
                internal;
        }


error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error-pages;
                internal;
        }
```